# Sending an UDP packet by raw socket in loopback

Tags: linux, raw-sockets

I have a socket `s`:

```
s = socket(AF_PACKET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
```

and with that socket I send a message with a `sendto` by a `loopback`.

There is another process that listens on `127.0.0.1:9999`, but it does not receive  packets sent by `s`.

Do you have any idea why?

I see sent packets in `tcpdump`. Address and port are correct. 
When I send a packet by common socket like `socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)` the packet is received.

Could you help me?

Comment: The sender and receiver need to match each other in which address family they use for their respective sockets. Sounds like the receiving program is not using `AF_PACKET`, but is using `AF_INET`, which is why that works

Comment: Are you sure you want to use AF_PACKET? Since you intend to use UDP, you probably want to use AF_INET, or since you are using local communications on linux, you could use AF_UNIX, and use a (temporary/fixed) filename as the address.

Comment: There are lot of possible reason why it fails. We could help better if you share little bit more the source code. For raw UDP sockets, I would use `socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_UDP)`. For normal UDP communication I propose to use `socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP)` .

Answer (score 0):

You have 0 for protocol, which works okay in most circumstances, but not so well for AF_PACKET.  From "man packet" : "protocol is the  IEEE  802.3 protocol  number  in  network  byte  order.  See the  include file for a list of allowed protocols."  Since you're trying to send IP traffic, you will want ETH_P_IP from there, which is 0x0800 rather than zero.

That tells the receiving OS to route the packet to the IP stack in the kernel.  I believe Wireshark labels it as the Type in the Ethernet layer.  Should be able to see it there.